# Place a div with a large border on top of another div without a border

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a "cutout" div on top of another div. The cutout div is the same size but has a large border. When I attempt to use the top, left,offset width and height of the first div and to place the second div it places the div coordinate including the border so it isn't on top of the other.

I'm not sure how place the second div in a way that it's on top of the other. Here is my code:

```js
let targetElement = document.querySelector(".div1");
let targetTop = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
let targetLeft = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;
let targetHeight = targetElement.offsetHeight;
let targetWidth = targetElement.offsetWidth;


let isolateElement = document.querySelector(".div2");
if(isolateElement){
 isolateElement.style.top =    (targetTop) +"px";     
isolateElement.style.left =    (targetLeft) +"px";     
isolateElement.style.height =    (targetHeight) +"px";     
isolateElement.style.width =    (targetWidth) +"px";   
isolateElement.style.position = "absolute";

console.log(targetTop);
console.log(targetLeft);
console.log(targetWidth);
console.log(targetHeight); 
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
}



.div2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
    background: transparent;
    border:400px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) ;
    left: -15%;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `calc()`:

```js
let targetElement = document.querySelector(".div1");
let targetHeight = targetElement.offsetHeight;
let targetWidth = targetElement.offsetWidth;


let isolateElement = document.querySelector(".div2");
if (isolateElement) {
  isolateElement.style.height = (targetHeight) + "px";
  isolateElement.style.width = (targetWidth) + "px";

}
```

```css
.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: transparent;
  border: 400px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  top:calc(50% - 400px);
  left:calc(50% - 400px);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Or use outline instead of border:

```js
let targetElement = document.querySelector(".div1");
let targetHeight = targetElement.offsetHeight;
let targetWidth = targetElement.offsetWidth;


let isolateElement = document.querySelector(".div2");
if(isolateElement){  
isolateElement.style.height =    (targetHeight) +"px";     
isolateElement.style.width =    (targetWidth) +"px"; 
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  outline: 400px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```